# Modify tool-tip of phpgrid dynamically

Tags: php, phpgrid

I am using data grid from `www.phpgrid.com` for my website. I want to customize the tool-tip to something custom. Which file should I mod and what should I do?

I saw a reference in their documentation :

```
http://phpgrid.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/33488-tool-tip-for-column-headers
```

But this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do?? The code is pretty self-explanatory. Replace "Column 1 header title" for the first column header, replace "Column 2 header title" for the second one, and so forth.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(0)").attr("title", "Column 1 header title");
    jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(1)").attr("title", "Column 2 header title");
    jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(2)").attr("title", "Column 3 header title");

});
```

Comment: i have title of books in the grid data cells. when user hovers over it, i want them to see a short description of the book in the tool-tip rather than the title itself.

Comment: That's exactly what "title" attribute does.  You should take a look w3school tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp. Mouse over the text and WAIT FOR ABOUT 1 SECOND so the tooltip can appear.